# Laravel eloquent deep count with relationship

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I want to get count from deep table and the relationship is A->B->C->D and I want total count of D. 
For example;
 
A: 3 Boss
B: 5 Managers
C: 8 Human Resources
D: 25 Employees
Imagine that every boss has managers and every manager has human resources and also every human resource has employees. 
How can I get total count every boss's employees' with Laravel. (For instance, first boss has 7 employees at the end.) Should I have to write hard sql code like joins or can I handle with eloquent?

By the way, my tables:
A: id, name
B: id, name
A and B has pivot table.
C: id, name
B and C has pivot table
D: id, name
C and D has pivot table

So far, I tried to:

```
$a = Boss::with("a.b.c.d")->where("id", 10)->first();
dd($a->b->c->d->count());
```

It just gave me d's count but I want to all of a's.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you have your Model relationships set up correctly it could be as simple as `A->B->C->D->count()`

Comment: I edited to question. Sorry for forgetting.

Comment: So to clarify you want a count of b, c, and d all together?

Comment: No @James, I just want to total count of D's which belongs to A.

Answer (score 3):

There is no native relationship for this case.

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with unlimited levels: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class A extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function d() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(D::class, ['a_b', B::class, 'b_c', C::class, 'c_d']);
    }
}

$count = A::find($id)->d()->count();
```